# Can't drag cubes through disintegration field with yellow gun

Tags: antichamber

On the puzzle "The Missing Pieces" it won't let me drag blocks all the way through the disintegration field over to the receptors.

I can drag the blocks about half way but then it refuses to let me drag them any further.

I can sometimes drag them BACK towards where I came from, but I can never drag them the full way.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you link a screenshot from what puzzle you are talking about, I dont remember having any trouble or the solution lies elswhere.

Comment: http://antichamber.wikia.com/wiki/The_Missing_Pieces

Comment: http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/35219203320059356/53DBD0902F1C265CAADAE3EDD687E9B50B92CFE8/1024x576.resizedimage that's a screenshot of the situation I am in. If I try to middle click any of those blocks it will not let me drag them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it and somehow experienced the same bug. However I've manage to overcome it by going back and re-entering the particles-field. I've recorded a short demo if you want to watch it [here on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6NQ1Puirjk).

Beware there is a small spoiler in the video :

> I have a red gun

Comment: I since worked out that you don't need to drag the cubes through to solve the puzzle, and now I have the same gun as you. When I did it I dragged the cubes along the floor, not up the top like you did. I did try to re-enter the field a few times and it didn't help. I'll accept your answer though because it seems to indicate that this is a bug with the game and not intended behaviour.